# Abort plan for Apollo 8

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, apollo-program, abort, free-return

What was the plan if the flight controller received a no-go prior to Apollo 8's traverse of the far side of the Moon? How would they have returned to Earth without the gravity assist from the Moon?

Comment: I guess you'd want to read [What If Apollo Astronauts Became Marooned in Lunar Orbit? (1968)](http://spaceflighthistory.blogspot.si/2015/08/failure-was-option-what-if-apollo_19.html) over at [DSFP's Spaceflight History](http://spaceflighthistory.blogspot.si/) (written by [David S. F. Portree](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/10905/david-s-f-portree), one of our members here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apollo 8 was on a free-return trajectory when approaching the moon. If there was a no-go for the lunar orbit insertion, or if the engine failed to fire, they would have returned to Earth needing only minor course correction (doable with the RCS thrusters, which had a terrific amount of redundancy) to get home.

Via [Americaspace.com](http://www.americaspace.com/?p=28278):

> During the translunar coast, the large Service Propulsion System (SPS) engine in the service module would be test-fired for a few seconds. If it refused to work, the astronauts could still be brought home safely, thanks to a safety feature built into Apollo 8’s trajectory design. Known as the “free return,” it would allow the crew to essentially loop around the Moon and use its gravitational influence to slingshot them back to Earth without using the SPS. In fact, if Borman, Lovell, and Anders did find themselves with a useless engine, they would only need to perform a couple of mid-course correction burns, using the service module’s thruster quads, to keep them on track for home.

Your question is a bit confused, though: the free return trajectory *is* a gravity assist trajectory, using the moon's gravity to sling the ship back towards Earth. It's simply set up long before the ship reaches the moon.

[This page has a nice animation](http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/free-return.htm) of the trajectory - after the ship leaves Earth, gravity is doing all the work. The Apollo missions after 11 switched to [a different profile](http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/hybrid-profile.htm), starting with a free return trajectory falling well short of the moon, then switching to a non-free-return with a midcourse correction.

Comment: So they would have still gone round the moon regardless?

Comment: In my head I kind of just had them off to one side of the Moon. They got the no-go and just turned around and came home.

Comment: In space you are always in some kind of orbit, there is no "turning around". Take a look at [this image](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-61beea31409bc1cef53fd52f1e0e8400?convert_to_webp=true).

Comment: I think that diagram is for the landing missions after A11 - I believe Apollo 8's free-return trajectory went behind the moon. http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/life-unbounded/crazy-wonderful-spacecraft-orbits/

Comment: Interesting; I seemed to recall that Apollo 12 also used a free-return trajectory, but apparently I was half wrong. [Apollo 12 was the first Apollo craft to use what NASA termed a "hybrid non-free-return trajectory".](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_12a_Summary.htm) In their words: "The hybrid profile was constrained so that a safe return using the descent propulsion system could be made following a failure to enter lunar orbit."

Comment: Yeah, by the time of A12 I suspect they had quite a bit of confidence in the SPS (the basic engine had been in use since '58). With DPS and RCS as backups, keeping free return "in sight" was enough of a safety option.

Comment: @BrianLynch: Well, you _can_ turn around; it just takes a humongous amount of propellant.  BTW, your link is broken.

Comment: Isn't this what Apollo 13 did? Just keep coasting behind the Moon and return to Earth without being captured by lunar gravity?

Comment: Yes, but at the time of the accident A13 was not on a free-return trajectory. It was close to one, and needed only small course corrections to reach it (plus a big burn shortly after the lunar flyby to shorten the return flight considerably.)